# Text menu with image - replacing image at the same time as changing text link color

Tags: jquery, css

I started to write the following code for link color change when hover over. And then decided to add an icon next the the text link. I was able to change image while hover over with JQuery.

Is there a way to change link color and icon at the same time while hovering on any of them? I'd appreciate if you can point me in the right direction.

HTML

```
<header class="main-header">
<div class="inner">
<nav>
<a href="/url1"><img src="/icon1.gif" alt="Menu 1" border="0" class="menu_calc"></a>
<a href="/url1">MENU 1</a>
</nav>
</div>
</header>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".menu_calc").hover(function() {
    $(this).attr("src","/icon1_hover.gif");
        }, function() {
    $(this).attr("src","/icon1.gif");
});
});
```

CSS

```
.main-header {
  background: #000000;
  height: 40px;
  min-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.inner {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 1200px;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.main-header nav {
  float:left;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-header nav a { margin-left: 10px; text-decoration: none; color: #FFFFFF;}
.main-header nav a:link { margin-left: 10px; text-decoration: none; color: #FFFFFF;}
.main-header nav a:visited { margin-left: 10px; text-decoration: none; color: #FFFFFF;}
.main-header nav a:active { margin-left: 10px; text-decoration: none; color: #FFFFFF;}
.main-header nav a:hover {text-decoration: none; color: #ff6101;}
```

here is my code:
[jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/00pmog3c/)

Comment: why don't you use :hover state css with background-image property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this code?

```css
a {
  background-image: url('icon1.gif');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 20px; /*Image width*/
}

a:hover {
  background-image: url('icon1_hover.gif');
  color: #ff6101;
}
```

```html
<a href="/url1">MENU 1</a>
```

Comment: This this it! Thanks!

Comment: Umm, but what if I have multiple menu items with different icons? How to apply multiple backgrounds?

Comment: Is there any way to apply this to a multiple menu items all with different images?

Comment: You should use alias for each item. ex: class="item-1", "item-2". Then define  in css .item-1{background-image: url(1.jpg)}, .item-2{background-image:url(2.jpg);}

Comment: Try to use Font Awesome Icons instead of images for rendering an icon in html. Have you tried this: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the image or icon at first in many ways. Such as ;

```
img { visibility:hidden; } or img{ opacity:0; }
```

Then when hover over any parent which is including both the link and image ;

```
parentElement:hover img { visibility:visible; }
```

or

```
 parentElement:hover img { opacity:1; }

parentElement:hover a { background-color:red; }
```